Cubic interpolation in OpenLayers
Using TileLayers, when the map is zoomed in beyond the maximum available data, OpenLayers does bilineal interpolation (unless disabled).
Is there a way to provide (client-side if possible) cubic interpolation instead, in runtime?
I can do cubic/lanczos interpolation on the map data using gdal_translate, but this increases the server storage requirements beyond what I have at my avail. I would need a dynamic solution, either client-side or server-side.
